# how to use priority_queue<pair<double, int> >

Tags: c++, c++14, priority-queue

I have recently learned about priority queues and I do not understand what the extra `<pair>` does.

How is it different from the normal `<int>` tag?

Comment: You're asking how a priority queue is different from a regular queue? Well, the priority queue puts a priority on its elements.

Comment: [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/) is a kind of tuple, which is a value created by bringing together two (or more) other values.

Answer (score 0):

A `priority_queue<int>` is a priority queue of `int`s.

A `priority_queue<pair<double, int>>` is a priority queue of `pair<double, int>`s.

There's nothing magical or special about it, it's just what the programmer decided she wanted.

A priority queue doesn't *have* to contain `int`s, nor is that the "normal" way to use such a container.